# hlssink does not split video and does not create a playlist

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer

I work with gstreamer and have the following pipeline:

```
   appsrc name=source is-live=true block=true format=GST_FORMAT_TIME
   caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1
   ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc  !
   h264parse config-interval=3  ! queue ! mpegtsmux !
   hlssink playlist-length=2 max-files=5
   playlist-location="/tmp/hls/stream.m3u8" playlist-root="/tmp/hls"
   location="/tmp/hls/fragment%06d.ts" target-duration=10
```

I feed the pipeline through appsrc, which is subscribed to the 'need-data' event in my application.

After starting the application, I expect to see the segments **fragment000000.ts**, **fragment000001.ts**, **fragment000002.ts** ...  **fragment00000N.ts** in the /tmp/hls folder. The playlist file **stream.m3u8** should also appear here.

But in fact, only **fragment000000.ts** appears in /tmp/hls  folder. This segment contains the entire video.

I can’t understand why my pipeline doesn’t segment the video.

There are so many examples of starting pipelines where the video source for hlssink is videotestsrc. For example,  everything works great if I run  the following:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc is-live=true ! video/x-raw, framerate=25/1, width=720, height=576, format=I420 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 key-int-max=25 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264 ! queue ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink playlist-length=10 max-files=20  playlist-location="/tmp/hls/stream.m3u8" location="/tmp/hls/fragment%06d.ts" target-duration=10
```

But I did not find any example of starting gstreamer using the **appsrc -> hlssink** scheme. Help please understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your encoder is not generating key frames, so hlssink has nowhere to "chop" the stream into segments. In the working example you posted, `key-int-max=25` tells the encoder every 25th frame should be a key frame.

Since you're using 10 second target duration, you should at least have a key frame every 10 seconds.